# creating a folder and putting spreadsheet automatically after submitting the form in google site

Tags: google-app-engine, google-docs

What i wanted is that i have created a form for registration in which after giving submit button i need to create a folders called product and catalog. In the product folder i need a spreadsheet which needs to be created everytime when a new person gets registered in the form.

registration form-->after submit-->product folder creation-->spreadsheet of the product.

Is this possible in google site??is there any google API for this??

Comment: A folder where? In Google Docs? On the user's computer? Under whose account? It's not clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: I need to create a folder in the google site within that a spreadsheet.Automatocally it shoould get created after submitting the form.Hope you got it now.

Answer (score 0):

You can't store file in GAE, you can store it into BigTable DB, of course you can use you Google docs account,
http://code.google.com/apis/documents/docs/3.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#CreateFolders
http://code.google.com/apis/spreadsheets/

Comment: Is there any standard tutorial to know more about google apps and google API?